# Visual Studio 2015 Preview - Full IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Any idea how to run ASP.NET 5 project in full IIS (not express) from within Visual Studio 2015 (via start debugging with F5 key)?

Atm I'm getting:

```
Couldn't determine an appropriate version of KRE to run.
```

I know it's not officially supported yet, but since IIS Express can do it, so should full IIS?!?

Comment: Did you ever manage resolve this problem? I'm trying to debug via IIS as well but can only get it to run via IIS after publishing the app...

Comment: @Zac if you're still having problems I posted a solution below

Comment: @rtpHarry Thanks for the tip - unfortunately, we decided we weren't ready for ASP.NET 5 yet. Still, we may revisit the decision when it goes RC and this may be useful then...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you created an ASP.NET 5 web application out of the template provided in VS 2015 Preview, then you can follow either of the approaches below:

- Run the `kpm pack` command to create the deployable package with the appropriate options.
  Example:
  `kpm pack --runtime KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2-10690 --out "C:\MyWebApps\WebApplication1" --wwwroot-out wwwroot --configuration Release`
- Right click on the web application project and do a `Publish` to local file system directory.

Once the above step is done, in IIS, you can create a virtual directory application (or Website if you wish) to this deployable package's `wwwroot` folder. Example: "C:\MyWebApps\WebApplication1\wwwroot"

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I will rephrase my questions. What I'm after is an ability to easily run ASP.NET 5 from within visual studio 2015 and still be able to debug.
Think starting debugging with F5.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with beta4.

Note that the names have changed now so instead of a KRE it's now a DNX, although IIS was still showing the error calling it KRE despite this.

Anyway the solution for me was to:

1. right click the project in question in Solution Explorer
2. select `"project name" Properties`
3. tick `Use Specific DNX version`
4. tell it exactly which one you want to use, for me that was `1.0.0-beta4`, `.NET Core`, `x64`

The project then ran in the browser for me.